# Log plot with error bars in matplotlib doesn't work

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]I'm trying to create a plot with the following components:

1. Scatter plot
2. Line of best fit with error bars.
3. Y scaled to be log.

So this is a standard log linear plot saved to a png, but whilst I can get the scatter plot working I cannot get the fitted line to plot on the diagram. I just get one blob. Here is the code that I am using:

```
   import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('Agg')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111,  xlim=(-2,2), ylim=(1,10E11))
    ax.scatter(x, y, s=1, c='black')
   line, = ax.semilogy([-0.5, 1], [-0.5*m+c, 1.0*m + c], color='red', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
    ax.errorbar(-0.5, -0.5*m+c, yerr=ser, marker='o', color='red')
    ax.errorbar(1, m * 1.0 + c, yerr=ser, marker='o', color='green')
    ax.set_yscale('log')
    fig.savefig('log.png')
```

I get the scatter plot. and the log scale, but not the fitted line or the error bar.

```
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
~50,000 points
m = gradient = 2.38329162e+09   
c = 1.24269722e+09
```

I've tried lots of variations, but I cannot seem to get the line plotted correctly. I cannot find one example of an error bar plot with log scale.

As an update, I could finally get the line working. It was due to the y heading below zero. However I cannot still get the error bars plotted. I only can get one whisker line plot (not four) and no horizontal joining lines.

matplotlib version: 1.2.0

Comment: Please provide examples of `x`, `y`, `m` and `c`.

Comment: You can't have negative numbers in a log scale and `c-m` is negative. Quite a bit actually ;) And you set your lower limit in `ylim`  to 1.

Comment: @hitzg I was expecting that matplotlib wiould handle this issue and plot what it can, but this must be the issue in throwing a spanner in the works. Duhh!

Comment: @Navonod as you can see in my answer, matplotlib actually handles the negative values (by just showing whatever is within the limits). Does that solve you problem then?

Comment: @hitzg In my case, got no line at all. I appreciate the answer.

Comment: what version of matplotlib?

Comment: You should update matplotlib. The example in my answer is done with 1.4.2 and all the lines are were they are supposed to be. Even negative values are handled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not provide any number, I had to guess.

But this works, so your data might be weird (have you zoomed in to see if `ser` is not just really small?)

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(500,1)*2 -1
y = np.random.rand(500,1)*1e10

m = gradient = 2.38329162e+09   
c = 1.24269722e+09
ser  = 1e10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,  xlim=(-2,2), ylim=(1,10E11))
ax.scatter(x, y, s=1, c='black')
ax.plot([-1, 1], [m * -1.0 + c, 1.0*m + c], color='red', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
ax.errorbar(-1, m * -1.0 + c, yerr=(ser), marker='o', color='green')
ax.errorbar(1, m * 1.0 + c, yerr=(ser), marker='o', color='green')
ax.set_yscale('log')
fig.savefig('log.png')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I still cannot get the error bars working. Error bars are only partially coming out. For example I just one of the whiskers and no vertical line associated with that point.

Comment: Please add a figure of what you get to your question.